# Change unique=True to unique=False from my model field

Tags: django, django-models

I have one field in my model with like this `name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)` but now that table/model have a lot of data and need to change the `True` to `False` but without having to drop the table and créate it again, **How can I do that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate the new migration using:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

The above will detect changes to your model and generate a migration class but no execute any sql yet.

To generate/apply the sql to the db:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

If you want to see the sql that will be executed before updating the db do this before `migrate`:

```
python sqlmigrate {app_label} {migration_module}
```

**EDIT:** The above will rename your table with suffix `__old`, create a new table and insert the data from the old to the new one, and then drop the original table. So not sure if this is what you want..

Another option would be to use plain sql to achieve what you want:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name;
```

But remember, in order keep your migrations updated for new runs, find the migration class that declares your field as unique and change `unique=True` to `unique=False`. If any other servers need to be updated you can run the drop constraint command there too so everything is in sync.

Comment: When I use `python manage.py makemigrations` I get "No changes detected"

Comment: Thanks, I do it with plain sql, obviously prefer to do it with django but I need solve this quickly.

Comment: Sure you can fix it with sql and adapt your migration scripts afterwards. How did you deal with migrations so far? Do you have a 0001_initial.py and any others in migrations dir?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the value to False in the model and then makemigrations and migrate. This will update all items in the DB to the new value. This is if you are using the newer version with South and not using syncdb.

Comment: Actually I'm using Django 1.8.5 so I don't use South